# Why can't my cat meow, unless she really wants in the house?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, vocalizations

My cat *can* meow, but only when she really wants in the house, other times she makes high pitched noises or no noise at all.

It's like, she opens her mouth, wait a few milliseconds, and a small squeak comes out. My other cat can meow perfectly, and they both come from the same house, where we adopted them because that house neglected them, and they were there for the same amount of time.

**Help?** ***meow***

*Some information on her:*

- she's an American short-fur, or something like that;
- when we got her, she was very flea-bitten;
- she also had worms;
- she had lots of fleas;
- her sister would strike her a lot.

Comment: some cats are born mute others can be mute after mistreatment,ask your vet about it at the next visit,my last cat was defenitly not mute and if she had been out in the rain when i was at work she gave me a very graphic description of her feelings about me and the weather when i came home.

Comment: is there a possibility the cat might be deaf and never have learnt how to meow.it must have been hard for a kitten to not be able to call for its mother,

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't my cat meow?

Then...

> My cat *can* meow

Okay then...

Cats vocalize differently regardless of how they're raised, much like how you and your siblings who were raised together developed different mannerisms. Cats aren't carbon copies of each other, their parents, or of some great ancestor. They're all different, and they all have different traits, characteristics, and quirks.

A quiet meow isn't a problem, especially when you already said that your cat meows when it feels like it.

Answer (score 0):

Your cat sounds lovely mine is the same. She opened her mouth for the first time and a squeak came out when she was 18yrs old. No one can tell me why. 
Get your baby checked by a vet if you can if not and is happy and eating and drinking don’t worry. 
I would love to know why too but no one knows. 
She may meow when there is more of a balance with the dominant cat. But it doesn’t sound like is he can.